# Matlab regexp; I would like to catch words between specific words

Tags: regex, matlab

I would like to catch words between specific words in Matlab regular expression.

For example, If line = 'aaaa\bbbbb\ccccc....\wwwww.xyz' is given, 
I would like to catch only wwwww.xyz.

aaaa ~ wwwww.xyz does not represent specific words and number of character- it means they can be **any** character **excluding** backslash and number of character can be more than 1. wwwww.xyz is always after last backslash. My problem is regexp(line,'\\.+\.xyz','match') does not always work since wwwww sometimes contain special character such as '-'.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Is your `line` actually a path? There are dedicated functions for that that should be used rather than resorting to slow `regexp` (especially because things like file separators are platform-dependent).

Comment: yes line is actually the path. but my actual line is not only path. In order to simplify my question, I took only path for line. My real line is like AAAA BBBBB ..... aaaa\bbbbb\ccccc....\wwwww.xyz DDDD...

Comment: Do you know if there is a path in each line? Can there be more than one path in a line (or no path)? What do mean by "catch words between specific words"? Does that mean that you know what the words just before or after the path, `'BBBBB'` and `'DDDD'`, are?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I realized the way I was asking gave people confusion. There is only one path in each line. There is nothing known words for aaaa.... wwwww, AAAA...DDDDD. Only known words is \ and .xyz

Comment: If you care about your code being portable, you may want to use the `filesep` predefined variable in constructing your regex.

Comment: Although it appears that you have found a solution to your problem, I encourage you to edit your question and rewrite it to state the problem clearly. The point of SO isn't just to be your personal coding assistant, but to also provide Q&As that are useful to other people with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you Must use regex for this, this regex should work:

```
[\\]?(?!.+\\)([^.]+\.[a-z]{3})
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/fL5oS5

Example data:

```
aaaa\bbbbb\ccccc\ww%20-www.xyz
www-654_33.xyz
```

Matches:

```
1.  ww%20-www.xyz
2.  www-654_33.xyz
```

Comment: @user2990048 - Great!  Well if this was helpful then please upvote it or select it as answer or both.  Thanks.  :)

Comment: This assumes there is a three letter extension on the file. That seems like an unnecessary restriction.

Comment: @Floris - yes, you're right.  my bad.  maybe something like {1,4} would be more suitable.  The OP gave no clue as to what type of files he is working with. Other than his actual example of `wwwww.xyz` of course..  :)

Comment: @MElliott I still think it is an unnecessary restriction - but that's perhaps from being more from the 'nix side of the universe. It is good to show OP the different possibilities. Re-reading the question it seems the `.xyz` is to be matched literally, in fact

Answer (score 0):

No solution provided here is likely to be 100% reliable unless you know that your data is carefully formatted (has the path string been escaped?). The question boils down to finding a word that is a valid path in line of text. It not so easy. We'll assume that all files have file extensions (this is not necessarily true in the context of paths). An arbitrary  path can then might look like any of the following:

```
'wwwww.x'
'wwwww.xyz'
'\wwwww.xyz'
'ccccc\wwwww.xyz'
'\ccccc\wwwww.xyz'
...

str = 'The quick brown fox aaaa\bbbbb\ccccc\wwwww.xyz jumped over the lazy dog.';
matches = regexp(str,'\s\\?([^.\s\\]+\\)*([^.\s]+\.\w+)\s','tokens');
file_name = matches{1}(2)
```

which returns (for all of the cases above the extension is slightly different for the first case though)

```
    file_name = 

    'wwwww.xyz'
```

If you know the filename extension is `'.xyz'`, then you can use this instead:

```
matches = regexp(str,'\s\\?([^.\s\\]+\\)*([^.\s]+\.xyz)\s','tokens');
```

By the way, for a path, the [`fileparts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html) function can be used:

```
str = 'aaaa\bbbbb\ccccc\wwwww.xyz';   % A Windows-only path
% str = 'aaaa/bbbbb/ccccc/wwwww.xyz'; % A UNiX or OS X path (works on Windows too)
[path_str,file_name,file_ext] = fileparts(str)
```

which returns

```
path_str =

aaaa\bbbbb\ccccc


file_name =

wwwww


file_ext =

.xyz
```

You can then get the filename with extension via

```
file_name_ext = [file_name file_ext];
```

Note also that that `path_str` omits the trailing file separator.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the only thing that your strings have in common is that there is a file path separator, and you are interested in everything "from the last file path separator to the first whitespace", then you could try

```
['[\' filesep ']([^\' filesep ']+?)(?:\s|$)']
```

which on Windows platform would reduce to

```
\\([^\\]+?)(?:\s|$)
```

Demo:

http://regex101.com/r/jW5tT1

If you want to match the extension literally (`.xyz` in your example), change it to

```
\\([^\\]+?\.xyz)(?:\s|$)
```

"Find a backslash followed by the fewest (`+?`) number of "not backslash" until literal `.xyz` followed by a white space or end of string"

[image]